# Why I get "undefined" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Could you please help, why do I get this `undefined` value instead of returning `a`?

```js
var a = 0;
var m = 888;
 
function sevens(m, a) {   
      if (m == 0) {
          document.write("Amount of 8's is "+a+"<br>");
          return a;
      } else {
         if(Math.floor(m % 10) == 8) {
             a++;
             sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);
         } else {
             sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);
         }
     }
 }
 
 document.write("in "+m + " " + "it is" + " " + sevens(m, a));
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function needs to return something in the `else` statement. Like this:

```
function sevens(m, a){   
              if(m == 0){
                  document.write("Amount of 8's is "+a+"<br>");
                  return a;
              }else{
                 if(Math.floor(m % 10) == 8){
                     a++;
                     return sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);
                 }else{
                     return sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: oh I see now, I have to add "return" in front of recursions, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are not `returning` the `function call` while doing a `recursion`,

```
if(Math.floor(m % 10) == 8){
  a++;
  return sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);
}else{
  return sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);
}
```

If you do not `return` anything inside a `function`, by default it will return `undefined`. Not in all the cases. That depends on the way you call the particular function.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you change the logic a bit, because you don't need an else part if in the then part the function is finished with `return`.

The other change is suspending `Math.floor` in combination with the remainder operator `%`. It returns always an integer value.

The third part is to move the call of `sevens` outside of the if statement, because it is anyway called.

```js
var a = 0,
    m = 888;

function sevens(m, a) {
    if (m == 0) {
        document.write("Amount of 8's is " + a + "<br>");
        return a;                                          // exit function, rest 
    }                                                      // of function is else part
    if (m % 10 == 8) {                                     // % --> int
        a++;
    }
    return sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);                  // return result of call
}

document.write("in " + m + " " + "it is" + " " + sevens(m, a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget the **return**, otherwise, I refactored a little bit the sevens function and you can run in code snippet.

```js
var a = 0;
var m = 888;

function sevens(m, a) {
  if (m === 0) {
    document.write("Amount of 8's is " + a + "<br>");
    return a;
  } 
  if (Math.floor(m % 10) === 8) {
    a += 1;
  }
  return sevens(Math.floor(m / 10), a);
}

document.write("in " + m + " " + "it is" + " " + sevens(m, a));
```